# Problem importing Matlab data

Tags: import, matlab

I saved a matlab file with csvwrite command and the import it in mathematica as

energ = Import["E.dat"]

but then I get as the output:

{{0.1}, {0.2}, {0.3}, {0.4}, {0.5}, {0.6} ...

Instead of {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, ...   as I'd like.

What can I do? I want to scatter plot two of this lists imported from matlab.

Comment: What does `Import["E.dat", "List"]` return?

Comment: Take a look at Flatten[ ]